# a non-matching fingerprint, an exception occurs in AuthenticateAsync()

Tags: plugins, xamarin.ios, crash, fingerprint

I have implemented finger touch authentication in my app.

in andorid it works fine in both case

but in IOS when I give non matching input it throws error and stays on same page closing fingertouch pop up.

anyone have idea about this?

please help

Comment: Could you please post more details? Are you using [Plugin.Fingerprint](https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint)? It works fine in my side on iOS.

Comment: yes i am using that one.

Comment: I test it in my side, it works fine. I'm using iOS 11, which version did you use?

Comment: i am also using 11

Comment: sorry..for unclear que.my ap doesnt crash but.it statys on same page and  that pop upfor fingertouch gets closed

Comment: Whether you set the parameter:`CancellationTokenSource`? If you have set the second parameter in `AuthenticateAsync`, the alert will dismiss after the time you have set.